# Apply group by and limit offset together in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `transactions` where data rows are stored with a date

Like

```
`trans_id` `amount` `tdate`
```

I want to filter that data like last 30 days, last 31st 60 days, last 61-90 days calculate the overall amount also

My queries are

For last 30 days

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amt FROM transactions GROUP BY DATE(tdate) ORDER BY DATE(tdate) DESC LIMIT 30
```

Working fine and show SUM of amount (last 30days)

But for last 31-60 days not working

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) AS amt FROM transactions GROUP BY DATE(tdate) ORDER BY DATE(tdate) DESC LIMIT 60,31
```

How to solve it ? I do want to include only 31 to 60 days amount only

Comment: This should be done using date column. LIMIT will not work.

Comment: Can you please rewrite it, I am using it in a PHP script , Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry it seems irreverent from question

Comment: Well, champions of liberty and all that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following: (It returns data between today and last 30 days)

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DateCol, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM Table
WHERE DateCol BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL
30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Or more precisely, this will do the trick:

```
DateCol BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

CURDATE() works for only date portion. If you have DateTime column, then NOW() will do.

Comment: No need of trick above column is working fine. thank you so much